Going out with daughters at night
Assalamualaikum, I want to ask you that if a woman has the permission of his husband and she is going with her daughters and she is also covered so can she go out at night for dinner?

The rule is that a woman is supposed to stay at her home and to not go out except when there is a valid necessity.
Necessities include things such as:

meeting her parents and other mahram relatives
taking part in a mourning or marriage of her relatives
going out to satisfy her personal needs such as going to the toilet in places where there is no attached toilet in homes, or to earn money or purchase necessities when she has no one else to provide it for her
going to meet a mufti or judge to inquire about something or to complain about something, provided that there is no other alternate
when she is not safe in her home such as when it catches fire or is about to collapse, or if she comes across a snake or intruder etc.
when she needs to go out to perform some other religious obligation, such as migration from the Dar al-Harb, pilgrimage, being a midwife, saving someone's life etc.
accompanying her husband when he has to travel on a long journey

It is only when she needs to go out for some necessity that the following conditions apply:

she must observe proper hijab and segregation from men
she must be safe from fitnah and any other harm
she must take permission from her husband depending on the situation
she must be accompanied by a mahram if the journey is long enough to require it, there are some exceptions to this when she needs to go out immediately and no mahram is available

The evidence for this includes:

وقرن في بيوتكن ولا تبرجن تبرج الجاهلية الأولى
And abide in your houses and do not display yourselves as [was] the display of the former times of ignorance.
— Quran 33:33


المرأة عورة، وإنها إذا خرجت استشرفها الشيطان، وإنها لا تكون إلى وجه الله أقرب منها في قعر بيتها
Woman is ‘awrah (that which must be concealed), and when she goes out the Shaytaan’s hopes are raised. She is never closer to Allah than in the inner part of her house.
— Sahih Ibn Khuzaimah and Saheeh Ibn Hibban


‏ قد أذن لكن أن تخرجن لحوائجكن
You have been allowed by Allah to go out for your needs
— Bukhari

Going out for dinner is usually not a necessity, as one can cook at home or get food delivered at home.
Ref: Mawsoo’ah al-Fiqhiyyah
